# Структура таблиц в базе данных для интернет магазина

Tags: база-данных

Пишу свой интернет магазин со своим блекджеком и путанами. В ходе наполнения магазина, я столкнулся с вопросом, а правильно ли? Правильно ли создана таблица в базе данных MySQL с описанием товаров и кучей различной информацией. Её оказалось настолько много, что я сейчас не уверен что всё правильно делаю. Пока это всё «в процессе», хочу сделать всё максимально грамотно. Теперь мне кажется, что логичнее всего не хранить всю информацию о товарах в одной таблице, а разделить на несколько. Правильно ли я начал думать или нет?
Можете привести примеры грамотной структуры ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Здесь](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) вы можете ознакомиться с примерами схем разных баз данных. Так как у вас магазин, ищите (Ctrl+F) термины shop, sale.

Answer (score 0):

Хранить всё в одной таблице нерационально. Вы не сможете её масштабировать. И к тому же, это не производительно.
Почитайте про нормализацию базы данных. (1я нормальная, 2я нормальная форма и т.д.. Всего их 5 форм, если мне не изменяет память). В своей идее, каждая следующая нормальная форма(НФ) сохраняет преимущества предыдущей, и считается лучше. В вашем случае, можно будет оставновится на 4НФ.
Если у вас интернет магазин, то скорей всего вы хотите храниться информацию о:

1. пользователях
2. товарах
3. покупаках\продажах

Вот вам уже 3 различные таблицы, которые могут быть связаны между собой посредством дополнительной, служебной таблицы. Которая будет связывать между собой все остальные.

p.s. Прежде чем создавать таблицу, постройку её схему на листике. Почитайте о Первичных и Вторичных ключах. Подумайте о том, как вы будете масштабировать, в случае, если вы захотите добавить новую таблицу(к примеру, отзывы покупателей).

Answer (score 0):

По моему скромному опыту, лучше начать с составления бизнес-плана, для того, чтобы определиться с планируемым количеством товаров-опций-клиентов.
Чтобы там не писалось в гуглах, масштабируемость, возможный рост, в 98% самописных магазинах этого не бывает, как определились с самого начала, так все и остается в тех же рамках плюс-минус 20%.
Если у вас будет до 10000 товаров, можете смело остаться на одной-двух-трех таблицах. И даже опции хранить в таблице с товарами, т.е. один товар - одна строка, в ней все опции, характеристики и т.д. Поверьте, этот мизер потянет даже хостинг за 50р в месяц.
Если у вас товаров около 100'000  - стоит задуматься о структуре EAV.
Если больше 1кк - пора придумывать свои фишки.  Если посмотрите мой соседний вопрос. там видно с какими трудностями я столкнулся, получив на выходе 5млн товаров, у каждого 10 опции и три картинки. Банальный просчет количества товаров по таблице в 5млн строк с фильтром по опции или по категории дает хорошую нагрузку на БД. При том я точно знаю, что количество товаров скоро превысит 10млн, без всяких бизнес-планов)))
При том количество клиентов может быть как мизерным, парадокс современной торговли.